# How to get State (of Country) information using Current Location Coordinates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, core-location

How do I get the information about state from location coordinates? Is there any third party framework or API which provides states/province from lat-long values?

Answer (score 2):

Pass updated CLLocation value in below method. There are various information that you can get from *CLPlacemark*

```
-(void)getLocationDetails:(CLLocation *)location{
    CLGeocoder *reverseGeocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
        [reverseGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        CLPlacemark *myPlacemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *countryCode = myPlacemark.ISOcountryCode;
        NSString *countryName = myPlacemark.country;
        NSString *cityName= myPlacemark.subAdministrativeArea;
        NSLog(@"My country code: %@ and countryName: %@ MyCity: %@", countryCode, countryName, cityName);
    }];
}
```

Comment: When I tried  CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:19.0760 longitude:72.8777]; it's giving me *My country code: IN and countryName: India MyCity: Mumbai*

Comment: Give me your latitude longitude value which you are trying.

Answer (score 2):

State can be obtained using placemark.administrativeArea.

```
CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude longitude:coordinate.longitude
                   ];
[ceo reverseGeocodeLocation:loc
          completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
              CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
              NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark);
              //String to hold address
              NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
              NSLog(@"addressDictionary %@", placemark.addressDictionary);

              NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.region);
              NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.country);  // Give Country Name
              NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.locality); // Extract the city name
              NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.name);
              NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.ocean);
              NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.postalCode);
              NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.subLocality);

              NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.location);
              //Print the location to console
              NSLog(@"I am currently at %@",locatedAt);

               NSLog(@"state name %@",placemark.administrativeArea);
              _City.text=[placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"City"];
              [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
          }

 ];
}
```

Comment: But it will add the abbreviation only. How can get the full name of state?

Answer (score 2):

You can get it using reverse geo code. See below example:

```
geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

//newlocation is CLLocation object you need to pass user location there.

[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            // placemark.administrativeArea is state of use

        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    }];
```

From CLPlacemark.h://Placemark dictionary contain other information of user will be as show below.

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *name; // eg. Apple Inc.
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *thoroughfare; // street address, eg. 1 Infinite Loop
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *subThoroughfare; // eg. 1
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *locality; // city, eg. Cupertino
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *subLocality; // neighborhood, common name, eg. Mission District
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *administrativeArea; // state, eg. CA
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *subAdministrativeArea; // county, eg. Santa Clara
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *postalCode; // zip code, eg. 95014
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *ISOcountryCode; // eg. US
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *country; // eg. United States
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *inlandWater; // eg. Lake Tahoe
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *ocean; // eg. Pacific Ocean
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *areasOfInterest; // eg. Golden Gate Park
```